# .NET Core web API: one controller is working but the other one is not

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a .net core web API project. I have two controllers and they have the same structure. However one of them is working but the other one is giving 404 error.

My code snippets are follows:

```
//mvc routing in the Configure method in the startup class
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
});
```

and my controllers are:

```
[Route("api/user")]
public class ManagerController : Controller
{
    //this is working
    [HttpGet("myitems/{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetItems(String id){...}
}

../api/user/myitems/123 is working


[Route("api/price")]
public class HistController : Controller
{

    //this is not working !!!
    [HttpGet("item/{id}")]
    private IActionResult GetItemPrice(String id) {...}
}

../api/price/item/123 is not working! (404 error)
```

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: why is that method `private`? Change it to `public IActionResult GetItemPrice`

Comment: Thanks @Developer. I was trying to solve the problem for the whole weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetItemPrice` method is `private`. It needs to be `public`.